# Is there a way in Kotlin to map through a list, referencing previous values of the new transformation?

Tags: kotlin

Pretty much the title. I want to map through a list to create a new list, but the logic for transforming each element depends on previous values that have been already transformed.

For a simple example, I have a list `val myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and I want to map through each value, where each new value is the sum of the current element plus the previous transformed element. Meaning, I want the result to be `[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]`. This is not a real scenario, just for sake of example.

I can map through my list but I don't know how to reference the new list that's currently being built:

```
myList.map { it + list_that's_currently_being_built[i-1] }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`runningReduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/running-reduce.html)

```
fun main() {
    val myList = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    val result = myList.runningReduce { acc, value -> acc + value }

    println(result) // [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
}
```

Comment: just as a note, this particular example can be simplified by doing `myList.runningReduce(Int::plus)`